# Firebase query error - incompatible types

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to implement a search function with the following code:

```
private void firebaseSearch(String searchText) {

Query firebaseSearchQuery = mRef.orderByChild("title").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");}
```

But, the java compiler throwing the following error:

```
error: incompatible types: com.google.firebase.database.Query cannot be converted to com.firebase.client.Query
```

The code above firebaseSearch method:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.Query;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class ArticleScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference mRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_article_screen);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("data");

}
```

Comment: share you logcat error instead of type manually

Comment: @RahulChokshi I've added it, please check.

Comment: Quick description of what causes this below. If you need help removing the older version, update your question to include your build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
com.google.firebase.database.Query firebaseSearchQuery = mRef.orderByChild("title").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");}
```

Look at return type of [orderByChild](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#orderByChild)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you include two versions of the Firebase SDK in your app's `build.gradle`, one 2.x and one more recent one. You will need to remove the 2.x versions, and change these:

```
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.Query;
```

to

```
import com.google.firebase.database.Firebase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
```